# Why does this one block of Javascript (D3) work, but not the other?

Tags: javascript, variables, d3.js, prototype

I can't tell if I'm not understanding something Javascript-specific, or if I'm not understanding how D3 is supposed to does things.

I'm simply trying to create a reusable way of generating these: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636

The following works just fine:

```
function ArcGraph(selector, color) {

    this.width = 80;
    this.height = 80;

    var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(25).outerRadius(40).startAngle(0);
    var svg = d3.select("body').append("svg").attr("width", this.width).attr("height", this.height).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + this.width * .5 + "," + this.height * .5 + ")");
    this.background = svg.append("path").datum({endAngle: tau}).style("fill", "#f5f8fd").attr("d", arc);
    this.foreground = svg.append("path").datum({endAngle: .127 * tau}).style("fill", color).attr("d", arc);

    this.foreground.transition().duration(750).call(arcTween, Math.random() * tau);

    function arcTween(transition, newAngle) {
        transition.attrTween("d", function(d) {
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
            return function(t) {
                d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
                return arc(d);
            };
        });
    }

}
```

But when I try and properly prototype it everything into functions, it stops working:

```
function ArcGraph(selector, color) {

    this.width = 80;
    this.height = 80;

    this.arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(25).outerRadius(40).startAngle(0);
    this.svg = d3.select("body').append("svg").attr("width", this.width).attr("height", this.height).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + this.width * .5 + "," + this.height * .5 + ")");
    this.background = this.svg.append("path").datum({endAngle: tau}).style("fill", "#f5f8fd").attr("d", this.arc);
    this.foreground = thus.svg.append("path").datum({endAngle: .127 * tau}).style("fill", color).attr("d", this.arc);

}

ArcGraph.prototype.renderArc = function() {

    this.foreground.transition().duration(750).call(arcTween, Math.random() * tau);

    function arcTween(transition, newAngle) {
        transition.attrTween("d", function(d) {
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
            return function(t) {
                d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
                return this.arc(d);
            };
        });
    }
}
```

The problem all lies in the "return this.arc(d)" moment. I hundreds of errors like this:

> Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,NaNA160,160 0 1,1 114.55205494059831,-111.70419288856652L71.59503433787394,-69.81512055535408A100,100 0 1,0 NaN,NaNZ"

What am I not understanding here? It's not like it doesn't see the variable 'this.arc'. Why would everything work when I declare arc as a variable, and not work in this latter case?

Answer (score 1):

`this.arc` inside a function, which is inside a method, is not the `this.arc` of your `ArcGraph`.

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/58wTN/

Comment: Gotcha - what's the correct way of accessing that 'parent' this.arc element from within the function?

Comment: You should somehow pass the parent instance of `ArcGraph` to the `arcTween` function. See this modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58wTN/1/